# Reshaping Numpy array repeating some elements

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have trained a NN in Keras with LSTM, so I have been using 3D tensors. Now I want to predict with a dataset and I have to insert a 3D tensor in my NN.

(In my case I used `features = 2` and `lookback = 2`, so input elements in LSTM are `(batch_size, lookback, features)`)

So, imagine this example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4]])
```

I need to do `a_2 = np.reshape(1, 2, 2)` to be able to insert it in the LSTM.

But if I have a bigger test dataset, like for instance:

```
b = np.array([[1, 2],
              [3, 4],
              [5, 6],
              [7, 8],
              [9, 10]])
```

I would need to convert it to a 3D array of this type:

```
b_2 = np.array([[[1, 2],
                 [3, 4]],

                [[3, 4],
                 [5, 6]],

                [[5, 6],
                 [7, 8]],

                [[7, 8],
                 [9, 10]]])
```

so in this case I have predictions for each `lookback` with the new point. I guess this could be done with a complicated solution using many `for` loops nested, but I wonder if there is more pythonic way. Thx.

Comment: Yes, thank you, they are both useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy.stack()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) as follows.

```
>>> np.stack((b[:-1], b[1:]), axis=1)
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 3,  4],
        [ 5,  6]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 7,  8],
        [ 9, 10]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for sliding windows and there's [`skimage's view_as_windows`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for that -

```
In [46]: from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

In [44]: features = 2; lookback = 2

In [45]: view_as_windows(b,(lookback, features))[:,0]
Out[45]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 3,  4]],

       [[ 3,  4],
        [ 5,  6]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [ 7,  8]],

       [[ 7,  8],
        [ 9, 10]]])
```